Looking for 1996 Subaru SVX ECU pinout
Looking for 1996 Subaru SVX ECU pinout
I have found for other years like 92 and 93 but are slightly different
1996 is OBD 2
Thanks in Advance

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I did an EG33 swap into a Impreza a few years ago. I've actually got an extra ECU for it, lol. I hadn't realized (but should have) the 96 had the OBDII ECU in it. I could definitely find you the 92 pinout, as that's the one I used, but the 96 appears elusive. We'll see if anyone pipes in.

I had a bad ECU and luckily found one in a junkyard in Tucson. Would love to have a spare. I found 92 pinout also, but on luck on 96 altough I think it is similar to 92 but not exact.
